# what could be preventing my transaction log autogrowth to be set to UNLIMITED?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log, configuration, auto-growth

I have been trying to set the autogrowth of one of my databases to `unlimited` but despite whatever I do it remains the same.

First thing I have checked if [something is holding any locks to my database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/216773):

```
select radhe='kill ' + cast(DTL.request_session_id as varchar(3))
      ,DTL.request_session_id
      ,DTL.resource_type
      ,DTL.request_type
      ,DTL.request_status
      ,DEST.TEXT
      , SP.spid
      , SP.blocked
      , SP.status
      , SP.loginame 
from sys.dm_tran_locks DTL
INNER JOIN sys.sysprocesses SP  
       ON DTL.request_session_id = SP.spid   
   --INNER JOIN sys.[dm_exec_requests] AS SDER ON SP.[spid] = [SDER].[session_id] 
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(SP.sql_handle) AS DEST  
where 1=1
  and resource_type = 'database' 
  and resource_database_id = db_id('junofinance')
  and request_type = 'LOCK' 
  and request_status = 'GRANT'
```

but there was nothing holding any database locks.
so I went ahead and ran the following:

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE [JUNOFinance] 
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'JUNOFinance_log', MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO
```

when I check about the log reuse I get the following:

```
select log_reuse_wait_desc, * from sys.databases
where name = 'junofinance'
```

[image]

but that is not the problem, as after I few times trying these scripts I got:
[image]

then when I check the log maxsize I still get it limited:

```
exec sp_helpdb 'junofinance'
```

[image]

I have even tried some silly things like disabling the autogrowth and setting it to UNLIMITED

```
USE [master]
GO

GO
ALTER DATABASE [JUNOFinance] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'JUNOFinance_log', MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 0)
GO
```

then it worked fine, go figure!

but then when I re-enabled it, it went back to the limitation:

```
USE [master]
GO

GO
ALTER DATABASE [JUNOFinance] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'JUNOFinance_log', FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )
GO
```

[image]

On this server in particular, I cannot upgrade it, so we are on:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU7) (KB4495256) - 13.0.5337.0 (X64)
>   May 16 2019 02:24:21   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise
>   Edition:  Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2
>   Datacenter 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Is it the only database presenting this behaviour on the instance?

Comment: I thought it was, as I only recently had to add a filegroup to this database and noticed this feature. However, now I realise that they're all behaving in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open BOL article [sys.database_files (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

you'll find that
`268435456` = Log file will grow to a maximum size of `2 TB`

`2 Tb` is the max size of SQL Server database `log file`, if you need it more than `2Tb` you add the second `log file`.

Here you can find [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014) that states that `2Tb` is the maximum `log file` size:

[image]

Comment: The max capacity link, also says "The following table specifies the maximum sizes and numbers of various objects that were tested in the SQL Server Utility." & "Log files per database" = 1, if you need more then 2TB of log, is adding a second log file, really a good idea? - Maybe I should post this as a new question?

Comment: @James Jenkins This is the only way to have your db log size > 2Tb. You just cannot specify more than 2Tb for log file as you'll get 5150 error: The size of a single log file must not be greater than 2 TB.

Comment: New question [SQL log file 2TB is not enough, now what?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/251455/21924)

Comment: But this is then a `new feature` as I have many databases showing the good old `unlimited` there

Comment: >>>But this is then a new feature<<< I don't think so, maybe it was old SSMS that just interpreted this number as "unlimited"? I have only 2014 and 2016 here, both of them shows 268435456, I did not pay attention to this in old versions as I always used sys.database_files to check sizes and it shows max size as -1 for both log and data files